# Using subdatasets after group_by

Tags: r, dplyr, dataset

Suppose I have a dataset, where graph_id is from 0 to 800

```
     x    y index graph_id
1 3327  535   0_0        0
2 3316  529   0_1        0
3 3307 2359   0_2        0
4 3296  652   0_3        0
5 3283 2999   0_4        0
6 3281   73   0_5        0
```

and I'd like to use each subdataset based on graph_id as an input to a mutate in a pipe.
Like this:

```
test <- data %>%
  group_by(graph_id) %>%
  select(x, y) %>%
  dist()
```

but, of course, I'm getting an error (because dist applies to all dataset, not subsets):

```
Adding missing grouping variables: `graph_id`
Error: cannot allocate vector of size 20.9 Gb
```

So,

Is it possible to perform such operations using just dplyr without lapply?

**Update**

The idea was to create new column based on subdataframes without creating additional variables. It's possible if you do it inside mutate (in my case), using `{.}` to work with initial dataframe:

```
data <- 
  data %>%
  mutate(id  = {.} %>%
               group_by(graph_id) %>%
               select(x, y) %>%
               do(a = dist(.) %>% 
                    as.matrix() %>% 
                    melt(varnames = c("row", "col")) %>% 
                    mutate(weight = 1/value *100) %>%
                    filter(row < col) %>%
                    rename(from = row,
                           to = col) %>%
                    graph_from_data_frame(directed = F) %>%
                    fastgreedy.community() %>%
                    membership()) %>%
               .['a'] %>%
               unlist() %>% 
               unname())
```

Comment: Have you tried `do(dist(.))`? The `do` verb maintains grouping.

Comment: Thank you!, it helped a lot

Comment: What is your desired output? `dist` is going to return a lower-triangle, so it'll take a little more manipulation. If your input group (subframe) has `m` rows, your output will have `m*(m-1)/2` values (in a matrix with `m-1` rows and columns), so you cannot just assign it to a new column, and `cbind`ing it will grow quickly. Your output might include two row indices (*from* and *to*) and the distance between them, is that what you were thinking?

Comment: Initially I had a dataframe of complete graphs: x, y - coordinates, graph_id - id of a graph
I wanted to split these graphs into several subgraphs using `membership` and `fastgreedy.community` functions. Input is a graph (created from subdataframe) and output is id of subgraph for each point (represented as a row in initial dataframe)

Comment: That explains how you want to group your data, not how you want the frame to look. I don't understand how to add *"a row in initial dataframe"* if the output has many more rows than the input. Could you alter your sample data to include, say, 3 different groups and 3-4 rows per group, and show what you would expect the output to look like for that sample input? It's really hard to talk around it when it isn't clear.